# rails dependent destroy looking for non existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dependent-destroy

I am getting error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "profiles_rsl_codes" does not exist LINE 5:

when I try to destroy a profile.

I have a table called `rsl_codes_profiles` and in my profile model I have

```
  has_many :rsl_codes_profiles, class_name: "RslCodesProfile", dependent: :destroy
```

and in my `RslCodesProfile` class I have:

```
class RslCodesProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rsl_code
  belongs_to :profile

  validates :rsl_code_id, :presence => true
  validates :profile_id, :presence => true
  validates :rel_type, :presence => true
end
```

there may have been some migrating and undoing of migration and changing name of that table and then remigrating in case that might have had an influence.

A global search of my application does not find any reference to `profiles_rsl_codes` or `ProfilesRslCodes` or the singular of those.

The error backtrace only points to where I do `@profile.destroy` and the rest of the trace is all framework stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to run `rake db:reset` to update your database schema

Comment: @fongfan999 I do not want to lose my data

Comment: Because you worked with migration in the wrong way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies to those who spent time trying to help me on this one. The mistake was in code I did not add to the question.

I had to change this in my RslCode model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :visible_rsl_codes, class_name: "RslCode", foreign_key: "code_visible_to_profile_ids"
has_and_belongs_to_many :visible_comment_rsl_codes, class_name: "RslCode", foreign_key: "comment_visible_to_profile_ids"
```

which was trying to use a field in RslCode that I had since removed `code_visible_to_profile_ids` and `comment_visible_to_profile_ids`

to this

```
has_many :code_rsl_code_profiles, -> { where rel_type: 'code' }, class_name: 'RslCodesProfile', source: :rsl_codes_profiles
has_many :visible_rsl_codes, :through => :code_rsl_code_profiles, class_name: 'RslCode', source: :rsl_code

has_many :comment_rsl_code_profiles, -> { where rel_type: 'comment' }, class_name: 'RslCodesProfile', source: :rsl_codes_profiles
has_many :visible_comment_rsl_codes, :through => :comment_rsl_code_profiles, class_name: 'RslCode', source: :rsl_code
```

as I added joins tables to achieve the result and did not adjust those relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate db `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: I do not want to lose my data